# Google Script: Issue getting variables to appear in automated email in proper formating

Tags: google-apps-script

I have set up automated emails from a google sheet, but numbers & dates it's referencing are not formatting them properly like they show in the sheets.  Can someone please assist me on what i would need to change to make the percentages not be normal numbers, to the second decimal place.  And the date to use a mm/dd/yyyy format.

```html
var EMAIL_DRAFTED = "EMAIL DRAFTED";

function weekly_report() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //replace with source ID
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Individual Report Emails');                         // replace with source Sheet tab name
  var startRow = 2;                                                                  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;                                              // Number of rows to process
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();                                            // Last column
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, lastColumn)                   // Fetch the data range of the active sheet
  var data = dataRange.getValues();                                                  // Fetch values for each row in the range
  
  // Work through each row in the spreadsheet
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];  
    // Assign each row a variable
    var Isa = row[0];                              // Col A: ISA
    var IsaEmail = row[1];                         // Col B: Email
    var LastWeekTotalAudits = row[12];             // Col M: Last Week Total Audits
    var LastWeekQualifiers = row[13];              // Col N: Last Week Qualifiers
    var LastWeekObjection = row[14];               // Col O: Last Week Objection
    var LastWeekTransferred = row[15];             // Col P: Last Week Transferred
    var LastWeekDocumented = row[16];              // Col Q: Last Week Documented
    var LastWeekDiction = row[17];                 // Col R: Last Week Diction
    var LastWeekTone = row[18];                    // Col S: Last Week Tone
    var LastWeekKnowledge = row[19];               // Col T: Last Week Knowledge
    var LastWeekAverage = row[20];                 // Col U: Last Week Average
    var LastWeekConversions = row[21];             // Col V: Last Week Conversions
    var WeekBeforeLastTotalAudits = row[22];       // Col W: Week Before Last Total Audits
    var WeekBeforeLastQualifiers = row[23];        // Col X: Week Before Last Qualifiers
    var WeekBeforeLastObjection = row[24];         // Col Y: Week Before Last Objection
    var WeekBeforeLastTransferred = row[25];       // Col Z: Week Before Last Transferred
    var WeekBeforeLastDocumented = row[26];        // Col AA: Week Before Last Documented
    var WeekBeforeLastDiction = row[27];           // Col AB: Week Before Last Diction
    var WeekBeforeLastTone = row[28];              // Col AC: Week Before Last Tone
    var WeekBeforeLastKnowledge = row[29];         // Col AD: Week Before Last Knowledge
    var WeekBeforeLastAverage = row[30];           // Col AE: Week Before Last Average
    var WeekBeforeLastConversions = row[31];       // Col AF: Week Before Last Conversions
    var LastWeekSoW = row[54];                     // Col BC: Last Week SoW
    var LastWeekEoW = row[55];                     // Col BD: Last Week EoW
    var WkDifTotalAudits = row[64];                // Col BM: WkDif Total Audits
    var WkDifQualifiers = row[65];                 // Col BN: WkDif Qualifiers
    var WkDifObjection = row[66];                  // Col BO: WkDif Objection
    var WkDifTransferred = row[67];                // Col BP: WkDif Transferred
    var WkDifDocumented = row[68];                 // Col BQ: WkDif Documented
    var WkDifDiction = row[69];                    // Col BR: WkDif Diction
    var WkDifTone = row[70];                       // Col BS: WkDif Tone
    var WkDifKnowledge = row[71];                  // Col BT: WkDif Knowledge
    var WkDifAverage = row[72];                    // Col BU: WkDif Average
    var WkDifConversions = row[73];                // Col BV: WkDif Conversions
    var emailStatus = row[84];                     // Col CG: Email Status
    
    // Prevent from drafing duplicates and from drafting emails without a recipient
    if (emailStatus !== EMAIL_DRAFTED && IsaEmail) {  
    
      // Build the email message
      var emailBody =  '<h2><strong>WEEKLY AUDIT REVIEW  </strong></h2>' ;
          emailBody += '<h3><strong>' + LastWeekSoW + ' - ' + LastWeekEoW + '  </strong></h3>' ;
          emailBody += '<hr />';
          emailBody += '<h3><strong>Last Week:  </strong></h3>' ;
          emailBody += '<p><strong>Audits Performed:        </strong>' + LastWeekTotalAudits + '<br /><strong>Avg Qualifiers %:  </strong>' + LastWeekQualifiers + '<br /><strong>Avg Objection %:  </strong>' + LastWeekObjection + '<br /><strong>Avg Transferred %:  </strong>' + LastWeekTransferred + '<br /><strong>Avg Documented %:  </strong>' + LastWeekDocumented + '<br /><strong>Avg Diction %:  </strong>' + LastWeekDiction + '<br /><strong>Avg Tone %:  </strong>' + LastWeekTone + '<br /><strong>Avg Knowledge %:  </strong>' + LastWeekKnowledge + '<br /><strong>Last Week Average:  </strong>' + LastWeekAverage + '</p>';
          emailBody += '<hr />';
          emailBody += '<h3><strong>Week Prior:  </strong></h3>' ;
          emailBody += '<p><strong>Audits Performed:  </strong>' + WeekBeforeLastTotalAudits + '<br /><strong>Avg Qualifiers %:  </strong>' + WeekBeforeLastQualifiers + '<br /><strong>Avg Objection %:  </strong>' + WeekBeforeLastObjection + '<br /><strong>Avg Transferred %:  </strong>' + WeekBeforeLastTransferred + '<br /><strong>Avg Documented %:  </strong>' + WeekBeforeLastDocumented + '<br /><strong>Avg Diction %:  </strong>' + WeekBeforeLastDiction + '<br /><strong>Avg Tone %:  </strong>' + WeekBeforeLastTone + '<br /><strong>Avg Knowledge %:  </strong>' + WeekBeforeLastKnowledge + '<br /><strong>Prior Week Average:  </strong>' + WeekBeforeLastAverage + '</p>';
          emailBody += '<hr />';
          emailBody += '<h3><strong>Variance:  </strong></h3>' ;
          emailBody += '<p><strong>Audits Performed:  </strong>' + WkDifTotalAudits + '<br /><strong>Avg Qualifiers %:  </strong>' + WkDifQualifiers + '<br /><strong>Avg Objection %:  </strong>' + WkDifObjection + '<br /><strong>Avg Transferred %:  </strong>' + WkDifTransferred + '<br /><strong>Avg Documented %:  </strong>' + WkDifDocumented + '<br /><strong>Avg Diction %:  </strong>' + WkDifDiction + '<br /><strong>Avg Tone %:  </strong>' + WkDifTone + '<br /><strong>Avg Knowledge %:  </strong>' + WkDifKnowledge + '<br /><strong>Avg Variance:  </strong>' + WkDifAverage + '</p>';
          emailBody += '<hr />';
          emailBody += '<p><strong>In the event of poor performance, a manager will review with you.  </strong>' ;
      
      // Create the email draft
      MailApp.sendEmail(
        IsaEmail,                                         // Recipient
        'Your Weekly Call Audit Review for' + LastWeekSoW + ' - ' + LastWeekEoW,  // Subject
        '',                                               // Body (plain text)
        {
        htmlBody: emailBody                               // Options: Body (HTML)
        }
      );
      
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, lastColumn).setValue(EMAIL_DRAFTED); // Update the last column with "EMAIL_DRAFTED"
      SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Make sure the last cell is updated right away
    }
  }
}
```

But it comes out looking like this in the emails:
[Example of Current Incorrect Email Formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsRXP.png)

Comment: Could you please share a copy of the spreadsheet you're working on? (free of sensitive information).

Comment: Here's a link to an example sheet that has data like the tab it pulls from in formating of tab

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ub5onR-R9V_2Tmmkmc59J6nZRMZ18Q3CqOXdSMA1IBE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This same sheet will drive weekly, monhtly, etc from same sheet, once i have this one perfected, just swap around which variables and a touch of wording.  I have all of it working correct, except getting the formatting from the sheet used into the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the display value, you would use [getDisplayValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues). You'd change the line with your data variable to this.

```
  var data = dataRange.getDisplayValues();// Fetch values for each row in the range
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  That worked
Can i take this a touch farther, what if i wanted to reference conditional formatting, when something is below 80% the number goes red in sheet, is there a way to mimic that as well?

Comment: getBackground will get you the background color regardless of how it is are set and then you could use them to setBackground color, if I'm understanding you correctly. Would you mind approving the response as well if it answered your question?

Comment: Not sure honestly if we are talking about the same thing.  Basically in sheet, if the number is lower than 80% the font turns red.  I wanted it to mirror that in the email.  Your initital solution was exactly what i needed and worked great to get the right format in the date and percentages, now was looking to step it up a notch to also make the number red font if below 80% like in the google sheet.

Comment: If your setting the font color via a conditional, getForegroundColor should return the hexadecimal code for it which you could use in an HTML email. I'm not sure if there's an easier path.

Answer (score 0):

- In order to limit the number of decimals to two, you can use [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```js
var numberToSend = numberFromSheet.toFixed(2);
```

- If you want it to show a percentage, you can do this instead:

```js
var numberToSend = (numberFromSheet * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
```

- In order to format the date according to your preferences, you can use [formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format):

```js
var dateToSend = Utilities.formatDate(dateFromSheet, yourTimeZone, "MM/dd/yyyy");
```

#### Reference:

- [Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)
- [Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)

I hope this is of any help.